# i'm implementing webview in my app to view my website inside the webview but it keep crashes and throw NPE in

Tags: webview, r.id

(it keep crash in this line of code saying attempting to invoke method..bla bla bla)

but the code has no errors but the webview does not open and crashes everytime

```
webView.findViewById(R.id.webSite);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.loadUrl("https://prayer-times.info/add-to-website/egypt/cairo/");
WebSettings  webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

anyone how a clue how to solve it

i tried nothing but updating the gradle appcompat version to previous version but also in vein.